# Symbols not displayed properly in custom fonts

Tags: html, fonts

I downloaded the Webfont Kit (for **Quicksand font**) from [font squirrel website](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/); and I am trying to display the word Erdös using the new font; using the HTML entry `&ouml;` however, does not seem to work.

Looking at [the list of glyphs for that font (Quicksand)](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand); I can see that they have the letter o (both capital letter and small letter) with two dots on top of it.

Here is what I'm getting:

[image]

As shown in the above picture, the other letters are displayed correctly (using the correct font); but not the o with two dots!

Here is my HTML code:

```
<h1 id="erdos">Erd&ouml;s</h1>
```

Where I specify `erdos` in my `css` file to use that font!

**Edit: I'm posting additional information/code about the question:**

I downloaded the `Webfont Kit` from the `Webfont Kit` tab from the [same page](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand).

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'QuicksandLight';
    src: url('fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand_Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand_Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand_Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand_Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/Quicksand/Quicksand_Light-webfont.svg#QuicksandLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1#erdos {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: quicksandlight;
}
```

I tested the output in both Chrome 27.0 and Firefox 21.0

The output of Chrome is:

[image]

The output of Firefox is:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using &#214; instead or &#246; for lower case

Comment: @DominicGreen: I just did; I'm still getting the same result!

Comment: The list on the page cited does *not* contain the letter “ö”. Did you cite a wrong page?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Actually, if you click on the _Glyphs_ tab on the same page, you will find &ouml; in the collection!

Comment: Right, it is there, and when I downloaded the .otf files and tested locally. letters like öäå show properly. Can you post the exact code you are using and specify how you tested things? Which browser(s) did you test on? Are you testing with the .otf files or with some converted files?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I updated my question with additional information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Webfont Kit](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand) page at FontSquirrel, you need to select “Don’t Subset” in the dropdown “Choose a Subset:”. The default there is “English”, which apparently means that only Ascii letters are included.

Comment: Actually it's only worked in Chrome :( - It's not working in Firefox! I'm still getting the same results!

Comment: @Thuglife, it could be a cache issue. If clearing cache does not help, test with differently named font files.